# D3.js, rect's group, animating single element (transition/transform?)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm pretty new in using svg's and D3.js, I'm having a following code:

```
var board = d3.select('.board')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', '100%')
            .attr('height', '100%');

var barsGroup = board.append('g').attr('id', 'barsGroup')
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data($scope.bars)
            .enter()
                .append('rect')
                .attr('width', function(data) {return data.width})
                .attr('height', function(data) {return data.height})
                .attr('x', function(data) {return data.x})
                .attr('y', function(data) {return data.y})
                .style({fill: '#547EEA'});

$scope.myFunction = function() 
    window.setInterval( function() {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 280);
        barsGroup.transition().attr('height', x).attr('y', 280-x);
    }, 300);
};
```

At first, I wanted to create group of rects, and animate them all as once, changing their height, and it's working fine with transition() method. But now I'm trying to animate them separately, one after another randomizing a number, setting single bar's height and moving to the next one.

I tried multiple ways, something like barsGroup.each(), barsGroup.selectAll('rects').each() an nothing works fine to me, could someone give me a hint, or help with solution?

Comment: It is possible to do this using `barsGroup.each()` or something similar, but in fact the easiest way would be to simply use `barsGroup.transition().duration(500).delay(function (d,i){return i*500;}).attr('height', x).attr('y', 280-x);`

Comment: Yeah sure, but what I properly want to do, is to randomize new height number (it's x in my example) for each bar, and animate them possibly at the one time. That's why I tried to use each(), but it's not working, I can't even use tranistion() inside of each() function.